# Count number of matches between two strings python

Tags: python, string, comparison, indices

Given two strings of equal length, how do I return the number of times that the strings have the same character at a given index?

So: `count_matches("bob","boa")` would give `2` as index `0` holds the same character and so does index `1`.

But, `count_matches('bob', 'bbo')` would only return `1` as the only index where the character is the same in both is index `0`. Although there are two `'b'`s in both, only *one* of those is at a corresponding index.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything so far?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified that I assume the strings to be the same length.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you mean the number of indices where the character is the same in both strings.

Therefore, I would do:

```
>>> sum(a==b for a, b in zip('bob', 'boa'))
2
```

Wrapping that in a function should be trivial.

Comment: Would fail for `sum(a==b for a, b in zip('bob', 'bba'))`; unless that is the expected behaviour.

Comment: @s16h I am basing my answer on the assumption that the OP means the number of matching characters across corresponding indices. The community seems to agree that this is the case.

Comment: this is incorrect, prints 1 for ` sum(a==b for a, b in zip('bob', 'bbo'))`

Comment: That's the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, that would be correct output, OP is looking for matches at corresponding indices only.

Comment: @AlexThornton, sorry, his question is badly worded, "pythonic way to count the number of matches between two strings in Python", there is no mention of index so counting matches in bbo and bob would be two.